# Network error after upgrade to 4.6.5

Tags: civicontribute, upgrade

CiviCRM: 4.6.5
Wordpress: 4.2.2

I have followed the instructions here: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850.0.html

All CiviCRM and Wordpress extensions are disabled.

Details:

When going into Contributions/Manage Contributions and trying to view the details of a contribution, I get the civiCRM error:

> Network Error Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in
>   your browser and try again.

On my google chrome console, I get error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   GET http://www.lafabriquecoop.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/con…id=405&action=view&context=dashboard&selectedChild=contribute&snippet=json 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem,

I had the stripe payment gateway configured with the extension disabled.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you got this "network error' when a civi pop up page came up, try the following.

Go to Admin > System Settings > Debug and turn on debug and back trace.

Next, instead of clicking on the Edit link for your Contribution etc, right click and make it open in a new Tab. This should avoid the pop up and cause the page to load as a proper page. if it does, then I suspect you may see the real error. If that is the case, then look in the output for the actual ERROR and paste here.

Then turn off debug.

Comment: Hey Peter - I'm getting the same "Network error" pop up message. I followed your steps, above. I see the Edit Membership screen now in the new tab but no info on the cause of the error. Here's the link to the page that opened in the tab - https://my.citizenactionny.org/civicrm/contact/view/membership?action=update&reset=1&cid=43&id=472&context=membership&selectedChild=member .

Comment: You had the cividiscount extension running. Does turning it off change things?

Comment: Yes Pete, disabling CiviDiscount fixed the error. Aargh!

Answer (score 0):

When experiencing the 'Network Error' bubble in CiviCRM 4.6 after a recent upgrade: review your Extensions in the Manage Extensions list and check to see if you have missed upgrading any of them to their 4.6 compatible version. If you have - hit the Upgrade link. If there is no newer version - then disable that Extension. I just had a 'Network Error' bubble because an Extension was trying to inject a button on the View Contribution screen. Solved after upgrading that Extension to its 4.6 compatible version.